# How to I search P_NAME(By Field name and get all field which are indexed) in Solr 4.6

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr

I am New in solr

I am Using solr 4.6 with asp.net C#

I have Index 2 field P_ID and P_NAME
P_ID is Unique
P_NAME is For Searchfield in schema.xml

Now When i write in solr browser query this :-- P_ID : 16 --> i get result:-

```
  {

    "P_ID": 16,

    "_version_": 1459925474501197800

  }
```

Instade of this i want

P_ID and P_NAME How can i get both field by P_ID And If How can i get full name From some character by fulltext search query, for e.g :- P_NAME : HP then I will Get P_NAME : HP PAVALION

Please Help ,

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the first thing to look at is to make sure the **P_NAME** field is indexed as text field (one example is the **text_general** from solr's sample [**schema**](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml?view=markup)). And make sure the field is stored. the following is just example

```
<field name="P_NAME" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```